Is the trailing pathing in multi-sig descriptors necessary?
I created a multisig wallet with BlueWallet, and I want to convert the config file to a descriptor:

Name: Multisig Vault
Policy: 2 of 3
Derivation: m/48'/0'/0'/2'
Format: P2WSH
1E74CA69: xpub65........................Qwg1Wd
9F40E694: xpub74hnJ........................cWoEszidc
derivation: m/48'/0'/2'/2'
B5B630B5: xpub6F9A........................Rb1VjK

I see in the docs that when making a wsh(sortedmulti()) descriptor, the keys usually have trailing pathing (example: [e6807791/44h/1h/0h]tpubDDAfvogaaAxaFJ6c15ht7Tq6ZmiqFYfrSmZsHu7tHXBgnjMZSHAeHSwhvjARNA6Qybon4ksPksjRbPDVp7yXA1KjTjSd5x18KHqbppnXP1s/0/*  ---> Here I am talking about the /0/*). I also saw in the docs that you want to make 2 descriptors; 1 for change addresses and 1 for regular addresses : "Now the multisig is created by importing the external and internal descriptors: wsh(sortedmulti(<M>,XPUB1/0/*,XPUB2/0/*,…,XPUBN/0/*)) and wsh(sortedmulti(<M>,XPUB1/1/*,XPUB2/1/*,…,XPUBN/1/*)) (one descriptor w/ 0 for receiving addresses and another w/ 1 for change)." Is that true? Or can I just ignore completely the trailing pathing and just do:

wsh(sortedmulti(2,[1E74CA69/48'/0'/0'/2']xpub65........................Qwg1Wd,[9F40E694/48'/0'/0'/2']xpub74hnJ........................cWoEszidc,[B5B630B5/48'/0'/2'/2']xpub6F9A........................Rb1VjK))


Hey Myles, perhaps the second question should be a separate topic, as how to get to descriptors from zpubs seems quite a bit away from whether you want separate descriptors for change and receive addresses. I edited your title to try and capture the gist of your first question. I find that trying to summarize what you are asking for rather than describing the category usually gets more interest—the categorization already happens via the tags anyway.

Thanks. I split up the questions so now it should be a little less cluttered.

The /* at he end is not mandatory, but does change the meaning, and dropping it is most probably not what you want.
Conceptually, if you have a m/48'/0'/0'/2' wallet, it means the keys your wallet uses are derived as (with m some master key):

m/48'/0'/0'/2'/0
m/48'/0'/0'/2'/1
m/48'/0'/0'/2'/2
...

In other words, it denotes a key chain consisting of multiple keys, each with their own derivation path.
The way to write that as a descriptor is as xpubM.../48'/0'/0'/2'/*, where xpubM... is the actual xpub corresponding to the master key m. In practice, you will precompute the xpub for just the derivation part m/48'/0'/0'/2' and just use xpub.../*.
You can just write "xpub...", but then you have a wallet consisting of just the single key corresponding to m/48'/0'/0'/2' itself, rather than the keys derived from that key. Similarly, you can just use xpub.../0, but then you have a wallet consisting of just the single key correspondong to m/48'/0'/0'/2'/0, which is probably just the first key you want rather than all of them.
